# Easy angle and point / Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am a beginner with Numpy/Matplotlib (and scientific python) and I find that very easy things are relatively complicated to do because they have to be done by hand. (like without having this awesome math environment)

I thought that at least there would be a possibility for example to easy get the angle of two intersecting lines.

I want to do the following. I have those three points:

```
 (q)  |
  \   |
   \  |
    \a|
     \|
     (p)
      |
      |
      |
     (o)
```

1. All what I want to do is to calculate the angle a.
2. Also later I want to get a point z which is relative to the origin (0,0) with the distance from p to q and the angle a.

The first thing is easy with math, first I calculate two vectors a1 and a2.
Then I calculate:

a = arccos( ( a1 * a2 ) / (|a1| * |a2|) )

and so on...

But how the hell do I do this in matplotlib?

Is there a way to "just" give the three points and it does everything?
I don't really see a advantage of doing this whole stuff on my own with having an math environment.

Comment: matplotlib is a plotting library and not supposed to help you with this kind of problems. You could however use NumPy/SciPy which does provide vector classes that have special functions that implement norm and scalar products etc., possibly an angle function, too.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry for confusion. I refered to MatplotLib, because it is the highest layer of scientific python with scipy-numpy-python underneath it. And since there is no name for this whole system, I refered to that part which uses those formentioned frameworks.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Numpy provides the same functionality math provides but working on both numbers and arrays. So you would do :

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arccos((a1 * a2) / (np.abs(a1) * np.abs(a2)))
```

Comment: Ah thank you! Thats awesome. I really would like to have a comprehensive Doc with a combination of Matplotlib/Scipy/Numpy as a whole math system.

Comment: The formula OP is looking for is `from numpy.linalg iport norm; from numpy import dot; np.arccos(dot(a1, a2) / (norm(a1) * norm(a2))`